# Parental controls: request device activity report from parent device

Tags: swift, android-activity, report, device

I'm developing an application with parental controls. I am creating 2 applications: one for the parent, the second for the child.

Family access is configured on the parent's device and Screen Time is activated.
Authorized on the child’s device using the child’s apple id.

I install the application on the child’s device, go through authorization, and the parent gives all the confirmation.

```
try? await AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization(for: .child)
```

I install the application on the parent’s device and go through authorization

```
try? await AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization(for: .individual)
```

Next, I select the list of applications that I want to track on the child’s device.

```
private struct ScreenTimeSelectAppsContentView: View {
    @State private var pickerIsPresented = false
    @ObservedObject var model: FASelectionsModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                pickerIsPresented = true
            } label: {
                Text("Select Apps")
            }
            .familyActivityPicker(
                isPresented: $pickerIsPresented,
                selection: $model.activitySelection
            )
        }
    }
}
```

For example, I select the Books application. On the child’s device, I open the Books application and use it for 10 seconds.

On the parent’s device, I request information about how long the Books application was used on the child’s device.

```
private struct ReportView: View {
    let filter: DeviceActivityFilter
    init(
        selectedApps: Set<ApplicationToken>,
        selectedCategories: Set<ActivityCategoryToken>,
        selectedWebDomains: Set<WebDomainToken>
    ) {
        self.filter = DeviceActivityFilter(
            segment: .daily(
                during: Calendar.current.dateInterval(
                   of: .weekOfYear, for: .now
                )!
            ),
            users: .children,
            devices: .init([.iPhone, .iPad]),
            applications: selectedApps,
            categories: selectedCategories,
            webDomains: selectedWebDomains
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DeviceActivityReport(.totalActivity, filter: filter)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TotalActivityReport: DeviceActivityReportScene {
    let context: DeviceActivityReport.Context = .totalActivity
    
    let content: (String) -> TotalActivityView
    
    func makeConfiguration(representing data: DeviceActivityResults<DeviceActivityData>) async -> String {
        var result: [String] = []
        
        for await item in data {
            for await segment in item.activitySegments {
                for await category in segment.categories {
                    for await application in category.applications {
                        let name = application.application.localizedDisplayName ?? "unknown"
                        let time = application.totalActivityDuration
                        result.append("\(name): \(time)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```

The response is an empty array.

If you request information about the time the Books app was used on your child's device (the same code, only on the child's device), the time will be displayed correctly. And only after this, for some time, the time will also be displayed correctly on the parent’s device. What am I missing and how to receive information on the use of applications on the child’s device on the parent’s device; I do not request this information on the child’s device.

Comment: Please clarify your problem as what i can understand is that your data is not getting updated on server in time and there may be a delay or it requires opening the app to update data and when app is in the background it is not updating data.

Comment: @HaseebHassanAsif The problem was that the app on the parent's device was not updating the app's usage data on the child's device.

Comment: @HaseebHassanAsifExample. We use the Books application on the child’s device for 1 minute. In the application on the parent's device, it requests a DeviceActivityReport - time of use is 1 minute. Then we use the application on the child’s device for another 2 minutes.
In the application on the parent's device, it requests a DeviceActivityReport - the usage time is also 1 minute, although it should already be 3 minutes.